# InstancePerLifetimeScope and InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope

Tags: c#, autofac

In Autofac, can someone explain what happens when I register a component the following way:

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeComponent>()
       .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(contextTag)
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Q1. Is this a valid way of registering components?

Q2. Does InstancePerLifetimeScope override the other? Will I get an exception if I try to resolve the component in the 'contextTag' scope?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Normally you use one of those. Read the documentation about them in the autofac wiki.

Comment: We have our own container structure with different context tags to manage our dependencies. When we hook up with the Autofac WCF, by default it looks in the Lifetime scope. Since, all dependencies are in the 'contextTag' scope, it fails to resolve them.
If I register the components in both scopes (like above), it is able to resolve them in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

A1. It is not invalid. But it is confusing to look at and understand the need.

A2. The component will be available in both scopes and will be resolved in the requested scope.

I would try to avoid this scenario. But if you cannot avoid it completely, it would be cleaner to register the component in different scopes using disparate autofac modules.